# Javascript random number in a specific range

Tags: javascript, random

Is there any other way to generate a random number from a specific range other than this:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
```

Comment: Why? Is this not good enough?

Comment: How is this not working for you?

Comment: I suspect there's some library somewhere which provides this - but since you can get it correct with just 1 line of code, why not put that in a function of your own if you need to use it a lot?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Comment: I'm sure you can but none will be as efficient as this one line you have here.

Comment: Yes. `Math.random() * (max - min) + min` is other than that.

Comment: @deceze it is good, i am still a beginner and just practicing and wanted to think of another way

Comment: @LucaKiebel it is working, i am still a beginner and just practicing and wanted to think of another way

Comment: Well, what you need is a good source of randomness, which is actually a harder problem than you might think. The standard API that Javascript exposes to get a good random number is `Math.random`. So that's all you got to work with, and if you want to extrapolate that to a specific range, this is how you do it.

Comment: Thank you all...

Answer (score -2):

Try this Example

```
var min = 1;
var max = 100;

Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

Comment: How does this enable one to set a min and max?

Comment: While this does provide a random number it's not within a user-specified range.

Comment: @Akaino Well, it *is* in a *very* specific range… 

Comment: @deceze corrected! :D

Comment: kindly check my post :D